# `__anon__` not defined in parallel computing in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to make one program of mine that uses Python Libraries NetworkX and Matplotlib imported using PyCall and it is returning a strange error that I am unable to understand.

The program is:

```
@everywhere function runTestGrid(;lenghtGrid=6,heightGrid=6,redundancyRange=0.1:0.1:0.1,failsRange=1:1:1,repetitionNumber=1,failType=1)

  d1 = length(redundancyRange)
  d2 = length(failsRange)
  d3 = repetitionNumber
  grid_data = SharedArray{Float64,3}((d1,d2,d3),init=0)
  nNodes = lenghtGrid*heightGrid - 1
  @sync @parallel for redundancyIndex in 1:1:d1
    redundancyValue = redundancyRange[redundancyIndex]
    gGrid = nx.grid_2d_graph(lenghtGrid,heightGrid,periodic=true)
    tGrid = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(gGrid)
    sGrid = System(gGrid,tGrid,redundancyValue)
    for repetitionIndex in 1:1:d3
      notServed = failureRecoveryRun(copySystem(sGrid),failsRange=failsRange,failType=failType,reconnectionMethod="single_route")
      for nFailsIndex in 1:1:d2
        grid_data[redundancyIndex,nFailsIndex,repetitionIndex] = (nNodes - notServed[nFailsIndex])/nNodes
      end
    end
  end
  writeDataFile("grid_data.txt",grid_data)
end
```

and I get the error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: __anon__ not defined
deserialize_module at ./serialize.jl:754
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:695
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:703
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
deserialize_expr at ./serialize.jl:882
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:693
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
deserialize_expr at ./serialize.jl:882
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:693
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
deserialize_expr at ./serialize.jl:882
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:693
deserialize_array at ./serialize.jl:871
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:672
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:1075
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:723
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:782
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:723
deserialize_array at ./serialize.jl:871
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:672
deserialize_typename at ./serialize.jl:938
deserialize at ./distributed/clusterserialize.jl:52
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:723
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
deserialize_datatype at ./serialize.jl:967
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:676
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
deserialize_datatype at ./serialize.jl:993
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:674
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:681
deserialize_msg at ./distributed/messages.jl:98
#99 at ./event.jl:73
Stacktrace:
 [1] #remotecall_fetch#141(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.Worker, ::Base.Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:354
 [2] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.Worker, ::Base.Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:346
 [3] #remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Base.Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
 [4] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Base.Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
 [5] call_on_owner(::Function, ::Future, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:440
 [6] wait(::Future) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:455
 [7] sync_end() at ./task.jl:274
 [8] macro expansion at ./task.jl:303 [inlined]
 [9] #runTestGrid#55(::Int64, ::Int64, ::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::StepRange{Int64,Int64}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Function) at projeto.jl:24
 [10] (::#kw##runTestGrid)(::Array{Any,1}, ::#runTestGrid) at ./<missing>:0
while loading projeto.jl, in expression starting on line 257
```

Being that the code on line 257 is simply the call of the function and that I do not define any `__anon__` variable in my program.

Comment: Are you adding the procesors before defining this function everywhere?

Comment: I run the program using julia -p 2 program.jl, which I believe adds the processors

Comment: Are you also importing all your PyCalled modules using ie. `@everywhere @pyimport networkx as nx`? And also, are all the other variables: `System`, `failureRecoveryRun`, `copySystem`, and `writeDataFile` also defined everywhere?